# JavaScript function call apparently not firing

Tags: javascript

I'm using an HTML5 canvas to create a simple web based game.

Currently, when my page loads, a number of images are displayed in random locations on the canvas, which the user is required to drag to their correct places.

This is fine, but I want to add a start button to the canvas, which the user will have to click before these images are displayed, in order to start playing the game.

I have the following JS function in my index.html page:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var sources = [];
        sources[0] = document.getElementById("building").src,
        sources[1] = document.getElementById("chair").src,
        sources[2] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
        sources[3] = document.getElementById("food").src,
        sources[4] = document.getElementById("fridge").src,
        sources[5] = document.getElementById("land").src,
        sources[6] = document.getElementById("money").src,
        sources[7] = document.getElementById("oven").src,
        sources[8] = document.getElementById("table").src,
        sources[9] = document.getElementById("van").src,

        sources[10] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
        sources[11] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
        sources[12] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
        sources[13] = document.getElementById("franchiseFee").src,
        sources[14] = document.getElementById("wages").src,

        sources[15] = document.getElementById("admin").src,
        sources[16] = document.getElementById("cleaners").src,
        sources[17] = document.getElementById("electricity").src,
        sources[18] = document.getElementById("insurance").src,
        sources[19] = document.getElementById("manager").src,
        sources[20] = document.getElementById("rates").src,
        sources[21] = document.getElementById("training").src,
        sources[22] = document.getElementById("water").src,

        sources[23] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
        sources[24] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
        sources[25] = document.getElementById("drink").src,

        sources[26] = document.getElementById("creditors").src,
        sources[27] = document.getElementById("electricity").src,
        sources[28] = document.getElementById("food").src,
        sources[29] = document.getElementById("hirePurchase").src,
        sources[30] = document.getElementById("loan").src,
        sources[31] = document.getElementById("overdraft").src,
        sources[32] = document.getElementById("payeTax").src,
        sources[33] = document.getElementById("tax").src

    drawStartButton();
    loadImages(sources, drawImage);
    drawGameElements();
    drawDescriptionBoxes();

};
```

All of the function calls to other functions at the end of this one are being called, and performing their intended functions, except the `drawStartButton();` one, which I've just added.

I don't quite understand why this function is not being called...
The code for `drawStartButton();` is in a separate JS file, and looks like this:

```
function drawStartButton(){
            image.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(image, 410.5, 120);
            };
            image.src = startButton;
```

Do I need to reference the file in which the function is stored? I haven't done for the other function calls, which are in the same JS file as `drawStartButton()`...

Does anyone have any ideas why this function isn't being called, and how I can ensure that it is called?

Comment: `image` is simply a variable that I've declared using the line `var image = new Image();` to hold the image being used at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a semicolon behind:

```
sources[33] = document.getElementById("tax").src
```

(Just good practice)

Also, make sure that all these elements exist (and are loaded) before trying to get their `src`'s (But you have a `onload` already, so that should be okay.)

Now, you can simplify all those `getElementById`'s a bit:

```
var sources = [],
    sourceNames = [
    'building',  'chair',       'drink',       'food',         'fridge',  'land',      'money',    'oven', 'table', 'van',
    'burger',    'chips',       'drink',       'franchiseFee', 'wages',                
    'admin',     'cleaners',    'electricity', 'insurance',    'manager', 'rates',     'training', 'water',
    'burger',    'chips',       'drink',                       
    'creditors', 'electricity', 'food',        'hirePurchase', 'loan',    'overdraft', 'payeTax',  'tax'
];

for(var i = 0, l = sourceNames.length; i < l; i++){
    sources[i] = document.getElementById(sourceNames[i]).src;
}
```

Your code is most likely breaking because of one of the `getElementById`'s returning `null`.
(Also, you have duplicates in there, is that on purpose?)

You can test this by using this loop instead:

```
for(var i = 0, l = sourceNames.length; i < l; i++){
    console.log('Getting ' + sourceNames[i]);
    sources[i] = document.getElementById(sourceNames[i]).src;
}
```

You'll see what element was last obtained.

You'll also have to make sure the file containing your `drawStartButton()` function is loaded first, otherwise, this function will not exist.

And finally:

Replace `image.src = startButton;` with `image.src = startButton.src;`

Comment: If the error is one of the `getElementsById` being `null`, the other functions would not be called also. But they are as OP said.

Comment: @Amberlamps: I just saw, yea... _"<...> for the other function calls, which are in the same JS file as drawStartButton()"_
I'm not quite sure what's breaking there.

Comment: OP does not say anything about the `image` variable in the `drawStartButton()` function.

Comment: He should `console.log` in that function, then, to check if it's not running, or if it's just not doing enything.

Comment: Yeah, I am guessing `drawStartButton()` is called but simply is not doing anything.

Comment: `image` is simply a variable that I've declared using the line `var image = new Image();` to hold the image being used at that point. Also, I've just added a `console.log` in the function, and it is running- the added log is the first thing to be displayed in the console when my page loads, so it is clearly the first function being called, which is what I want. Do you have any idea why it isn't doing anything?

Comment: Before `image.src = startButton;`, can you `console.log(startButton)`?

Comment: I've done that, and the log is displaying all of the properties of the startButton image: `<img id="startButton" width="179" height="180" href="javascript:drawLevelOneElements();" alt="Start Button" src="images/startButton.png">`

Comment: Well there's your problem!
Replace `image.src = startButton;` with `image.src = startButton.src;`

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks very much for your help with that! Just out of interest, and to clear up my understanding- why does it require that I specify that it's the startButton's source that I want to use, and not the startButton itself? Is it because the startButton is just an object, but I need what the object is referring to?

Comment: The `src` is a property of the `startButton`. When assigning a `src`, a `String` is expected, and the `startButton` is a DOM Element. You'll have to pass the element's `src`, then.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. I have a follow on question, which I'd be grateful if you could help me out with? The way it's now working, is that all of the functions are called with the `window.onload` function- so the start button, and all of the images/ game elements, etc for playing the game are all displayed on the canvas as soon as the page loads.

Comment: What I'd like to happen, is that just the start button be displayed, and once it is clicked, then everything else appears. I've tried commenting out the calls to `loadImages`, `drawGameElements` and `drawDescriptionBoxes`, but nothing different happens when `drawGameElements` and `drawDescriptionBoxes` are commented out- i.e. the game elements and description boxes are still displayed on the canvas. When I comment out the call to `loadImages`, the canvas is no longer displayed on the page when it loads... any ideas how I can put this right?

Comment: Without your HTML, I really can't say a lot about that.
Usually, you'd want to set the style of the elements you don't want to show directly to `display:none`, and then remove that when you click the `start` button.

Comment: How would I set the style of the elements to `display:none`? Can that be done from within the JavaScript, or is it an HTML thing? Would it help if I copy my HTML into the question?

Comment: You'll probably want to submit a new question for that.

Comment: Ok fair enough. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have included the other javascript file before this one in your html file, then everything should work just fine.  Also make sure you close your function body with a `}` although I have a feeling that's a copy paste error.

Also as others have explained you need ; to end each statement in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having this long list of application specific id names in your javascript code you should consider grabbing those html elements by a class they have in common.

```
<img class="preload_image" src"...">
```

and in your javascript something like

```
var preload_images = document.getElementsByClassName('preload_image');
var sources = [];
for(var i = 0;i < preload_images.length;i++){
sources.push(preload_images[i].src);
}
```

this is keeping your code cleaner and you can make sure something gets preloaded by just adding a class to the tag instead of adding the tag and then having to go to your js file and add the id of your tag to your sources list. And also your code remains more flexible as you can simply use it in any other project without making any changes to it.

Comment: This is a somewhat good advice, but not an answer. Also `getElementsByClassName` is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: your right next time I will write a comment. 
As long as there is no information on where image var comes from (which is probably the reason for his code not to work) I thought it would be a good hint for better code structure. And of course to do things like querying for elements one should use jquery to prevent compatibility errors